# php echo certain character from string

Tags: php, json

I have this string

```
{"CALL CENTER":"CALL CENTER"}
```

I need to print `CALL CENTER` and I have tried using

```
substr($mystring, strpos($mystring, ":") + 1)
```

It gives me `"CALL CENTER"}`

How can I remove the special character from the result?

Comment: What you have there is called JSON. There's no need for manual string cutting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use json_decode with the assoc array flag set to true and then you can just access the data in the array instead of parsing the string yourself.

```
$jsonArray = json_decode('{"CALL CENTER":"CALL CENTER"}', true);
echo $jsonArray['CALL CENTER']; // CALL CENTER

$jsonArray = json_decode('{"CALL CENTER":"CALL CENTER 2"}', true);
echo $jsonArray['CALL CENTER']; // CALL CENTER 2
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7650e1b9e705318e31c2b02f44ed05f9ee201d13

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `trim()` function:

```
$mystring = trim($mystring, '"}');
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: I still get the quotes ""

Comment: The second parameter is a list of characters, put " into the list and they will trimed from the front and back of the string: `trim($str, '"}');`

Comment: Don't use trim or any other string handling functions to decode json. The string is probably coming from an API and can expand and become larger any day. Handle it as a json, anything else is foolish in my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas When you expect JSON-Data, then this is true. But: this was not clear from the question, just that the string contains a JSON-like format (btw: transform JSON-Data without error-handling is a bit foolish too, didn't you think so?)

Comment: "when you expect json data"? It is json. Period. I would be surprised if it's a string with both json and "other text" combined in that string. And even if it is, remove the "text" and handle the rest as json.